# Ubuntu 18.04 SSD sometimes freeze for seconds

Tags: 18.04, ssd, freeze

I have Ubuntu 18.04 in two computers (the same hardware) and sometimes during the day, the led of the SSD is lighten continual  for a few seconds (almost 30) and the computer practically freezes during this time, happens randomly, for example, with something simple like open `gedit`.

In the first place I installed Pop!_OS 18.10 but I removed it thinking that it was the problem.

Then I installed Ubuntu 18.04, but the problem continues, I also removed swap partition.

And I checked the SSD with smarttools and everything seems fine.

The SSD patitions:

```
   Device                    Start             End        Sectors        Size Type
  /dev/sda1                  2048         1953791        1951744        953M EFI System           
  /dev/sda2               1953792        99610623       97656832       46.6G Linux filesystem
  /dev/sda3              99610624       937701375      838090752      399.6G Linux filesystem
```

I was testing with some commands and for explame, when is failing:

```
sudo hdparm -t /dev/sda
/dev/sda:
 Timing buffered disk reads:   2 MB in 16.79 seconds = 121.97 kB/sec
```

And normal:

```
sudo hdparm -t /dev/sda
/dev/sda:
 Timing buffered disk reads: 1004 MB in  3.00 seconds = 334.33 MB/sec
```

SSD Info:

```
Device Model:     KINGSTON SA400S37480G
Firmware Version: SBFKB1C2
User Capacity:    480 103 981 056 bytes [480 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Fri Jan  4 16:43:40 2019 MST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
```

- Motherboar: Gigabyte H310M H
- CPU: Intel (R) Core (TM) i5-8400 CPU 2.80GHz
- Memory: KINGSTON HYPER X FURY 8GB DDR4 2400MHZ x 2

  ```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
   Mem:          15G        6.6G        3.2G        904M        5.7G        7.8G
  ```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Disabling swap was not a sensible step to do in this case. At best it changed nothing. At worst it made the problem worse and you lost some useful information that could have helped debugging the problem. It would have been useful to know how much swap was in use and how much was free before it was disabled. There is however still other useful information for you to look at. You can run `dmesg` in a terminal to see kernel logs currently in memory. Additionally you can look in `/var/log/syslog` where the most important entries from the kernel logs are saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same problem here. Solved by firmware update: **SBFKB1C3** (update tool only available for MS Windows: https://www.kingston.com/us/support/technical/ssdmanager).